# Reordering dropdown list on Modelform in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I am using Status table with 3 statuses used for reports. Each report is going through 3 phases (non-numerical), but now I have to implement new phase that has to be between phase 2 and 3 in earlier sequence.
Status table has only 2 columns: status_id (pk) and type

The problem I got is when I am showing drop down list (in modelForm), values appear sorted by primary key.

What is best practice solution for this?

p.s. It feels stupid to change the "type" in the database in order to get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an extra field, say `custom_order` to the Status model and then override the **init**() method of the ModelForm definition to alter the queryset of that field, like,

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fileds['type'].queryset=Status.objects.all().order_by('custom_order')
```